# How can I fix  a glitch with the Kina Gratitude Crystal sidequest?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I have completed all the sidequests for the gratitude crystals (and found all the ones in the wild), but realized I was still five short (75).

In trying to discover the issue, I realized the game had not recognized that I had completed the plow needed request from Kina, when in fact I had got Guld from Eldin Volcano and brought him to Kina (and received the crystals). But now Kina is again talking to Link about needing someone to plow the field, and Guld is back in Eldin volcano saying he wishes he could go to the sky.

However, I cannot get Fi to appear once again in Kina's presence to set Guld on my dowsing function, so I cannot get Guld back up to the sky. This has basically voided my ability to complete the Gratitude Crystals sidequest and get the Tycoon wallet, which seriously pisses me off.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: There must be a reason why the game put Guld back in Eldin Volcano and basically reset the quest (yet not allowing for it to get started up again). Do you remember when you did it, what you did right before, and right after first completing this quest? Was it the last quest you did for example, and when/ where did you save? The more info you have, the better, and you could ask nintendo support, so they can update the Skyward Sword save file channel.

Answer (score 2):

In the Wii Shop Channel there is a new channel for fixing the save files for the progression bug in *Skyward Sword*. Back up your save file and run that application on your save to see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by talking to the pumpkin man again at night and saying that I'll play the harp again. I did decent and he gave me a piece of heart again. This basically reset it for me and Kina asked for help again in the morning and I was able to set a dowsing target with Fi.